# How to make node js & npm visible from another docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, npm

I have a Jenkins instance running inside docker container. In Jenkins I have a pipeline that clones source code and executes command: `sh 'npm install'`

Because node & npm are installed on my host machine and not in a docker instance - I get the error:
`npm: not found`

What is a right way for installing/adding nodejs & npm into the docker container with Jenkins so it may use it?

Comment: Which image are you using in that container?